# グラフ上のトレンドライン引き変針点の算定したい

Tags: python, python3

1秒間隔のある物体の緯度・経度座標とこの物体が向かうコースのデータがあります。
このデータから毎秒のコースの変化量を計算し、図1のように表示しました。（X軸時間、Y軸degree）
この物体はコースを真っ直ぐ維持して行っても、外力の影響によりコースが変化してしまいます。
そのため、図2のようにグラフ上にトレンドラインを引くごとで、
外力を無視したコースの変化傾向がわかると思われます。

**物体のコース変化グラフ**
[image: 物体のコース変化グラフ]

**トレンドライン仮定図**
[image: トレンドライン仮定図]

図1を図2のように傾向線表示し、傾向線によりエリアを区切り、
傾向線が変わりはじめるところを変針点としたいです。

図3は物体の軌跡を描いた図であります。（x軸経度、y軸緯度）
最終的には傾向線が変わり始めるときの時間を調査し、
その時間に該当する緯度・経度座標をデータの中から洗いだしたいです。

この内容に関して参照できる資料などがあれば教えていただけますでしょうか。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

**完成図**
[image: 完成図]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[この辺のスライド](http://www.mech.tohoku-gakuin.ac.jp/rde/contents/sendai/mechatro/archive/RMSeminar_No07_s4.pdf)pp.11-14はいかがでしょうか。

変針点を算定したい場合は、微分して極値を求めるのが一番楽に実装できると思います。
その変化量（図１）の変化量が、加速度に相当します。
この加速度が大きく変化した部分を変針点とするのが良いのではないでしょうか？

センサから得た値(i)のリスト
->[-1, 0, 3, 2, 1, -1, 0, 1, -2]

センサから得た値(i+1)とその前の値の差(i)
->[0-(-1), 3-0, 2-3, 1-2, -1-1, 0-(-1), 1-0, -2-1]
=[1, 3, -1, -1, -2, 1, 1, -3]
->大きく変化した所（仮に±4とする）が極値(3から-1, 1から-3)となり、その時間(index)が変針点といえる

ただし、前述のように大きく変化した部分（=閾値)を自分で決める必要があります。
閾値を求める際は、とりあえず経験的に行う方法も良いですが、
[画像処理の大津の手法](https://algorithm.joho.info/image-processing/otsu-thresholding/)を応用できるかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。参照いたします。